# Как лучше сказать об исчезновении фейерверка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

В первой части музыкальный фейерверк вспыхнул, а во второй он погас (пропал, исчез, рассыпался).

Answer (score 1):

У каждого свои ощущения и ассоциации. Вот, может быть, эти глаголы вам подойдут?

Затих, растаял, растворился, померк, угас, догорел, потух, испарился, рассеялся, истаял.

Последние мерцающие брызги проплыли, померкли и угасли [совсем].
Разметался по небу бледным (блеклым) сиянием и растаял.
Разлетелся затухающими искрами и растворился в темноте с последним аккордом.

Answer (score 1):

Ну поскольку фейерверк это всё-таки "werk", то на мой взгляд, подходящим выглядел бы глагол закончился или окончился.